# JWPlayer mp3 Captions in Playlist

Tags: mp3, jwplayer, playlist, caption, subtitle

I'm using `JWPlayer v6.8.4616..`

When i test it with a Single `audio/mp3` file, with Caption, it works. For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer("theplayer").setup({
        file: "http://www.example.com/audio1.mp3",
        tracks: [{
            file: "http://www.example.com/audio1.srt"   
        }]
    });
</script>
```

The `Audio/mp3` file is playing along with Caption on it.

---

But when i test with the `Playlist`, the Captions are **shown only on the Video Tracks**, but not on the Audio/mp3 Tracks.

Like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer("theplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            file: "http://www.example.com/video1.mp4",
            title: "Video Track (1)",
            tracks: [{
                file: "http://www.example.com/video1.srt", 
                label: "English",
                kind: "captions",
                "default": true 
            }]
        },{
            file: "http://www.example.com/video2.mp4",
            title: "Video Track (2)",
            tracks: [{
                file: "http://www.example.com/video2.srt",
                label: "English",
                kind: "captions",
                "default": true 
            }]
        },{
            file: "http://www.example.com/audio1.mp3",
            title: "Audio Track (1)",
            tracks: [{
                file: "http://www.example.com/audio1.srt",
                label: "English",
                kind: "captions",
                "default": true 
            }]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

Why is it and how to have Captions on the Audio/mp3 Tracks in the Playlist, please?

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: Hi @EthanJWPlayer (the link is sent to you via Email) as i mentioned, the `MP3s` + `Captions` + `Playlist` is not ideal? (I mean, something like, `MP3 Playlist with Captions Showing`) Or can you please show me a working example for the combination of those three things, please? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions has an example of this, scroll down the page at bit. The same thing can be used for audio.

Comment: Hi @EthanJWPlayer as in my provided Link in my email, you can see it is not happening in the combination of, mp3 + caption + playlist :(

Comment: What if you use just mp3 + captions? Does it work in that case?